# Can someone help me fix this jumpscript?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Im trying to make my character jump in unity2D,the jump itself works but i cant properly check if my player touches the ground.
I get 2 errors in the unity console.

the first one :
Physics2D does not contain a defenition for OverLapArea.

the second error :
Vector2 does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments.

(also i apologise for my bad english,its not my native language)

The script :

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Security.Cryptography;

using UnityEngine;

public class jump : MonoBehaviour

{
public bool IsGrounded;
public LayerMask platfomLayer;
    
 public Rigidbody2D rb2D ;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
  
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
  IsGrounded = Physics2D.OverLapArea (new Vector2(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.x - 0.5f),
        new Vector2(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y - 0, 51f),platfomLayer);
     
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && IsGrounded)  rb2D.AddForce(transform.up * 2000f);

        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are both correct.

OverLapArea is spelled correctly but capitalized wrong.  Unity references are case-sensitive.

You are indeed trying to pass 3 values into a new Vector2.  Look carefully at what you're passing into your second new Vector2 value.  You have three values separated by commas within the parenthesis.  It looks like you mis-typed "0.5f" as "0, 51f"

Comment: You're welcome.  Remember to accept an answer if it solved your problem.  It'll give reputation, and let other users know you don't still need an answer to the question :)

Comment: man i feel stupid now , anyway Thanks a bunch it really helped.i finnaly cleared the errors, but i still cant properly check if my player is on the ground ,do you know what might be the cause ?  Also have a great day my good sir.